# Remove Radio button for several drop-down options

Tags: file-upload, choice-field, sharepoint-library

I deal with Document Library in SharePoint 13.

When uploading the document, I need the users to choose an Option from pretty Long drop-down list in one of library columns (currently it is in radio-buttons view so that the users can see all the available Options).

For instance, let it be:

```
FRUITS
-bananas
-apples
BERRIES
-cranberry
-blueberry
```

I don`t want users to choose FRUITS or BERRIES since These two are only headers.

Comment: did you try to create new NewForm and in SPD edit that form? Sounds like easy thing.

Comment: thank you @EricAlexander , SPD is unavailable... and InfoPath for doc library is not the solution...

Comment: The only way I can think of to do something like this without Designer or InfoPath, and without buying 3rd party software, is to make a new list for the categories, another list for the options with a lookup to the categories, add lookups to both of these lists in  your current list, and then use javascript to cascade the dropdowns.